# how to open jquery ui modal after page redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I want to redirect users back to a modal they used to input some data with, how do i do that in jquery ui ?

my shot so far :

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
    echo "<script>";
    echo "alert ('Success')";
    echo"</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location =\"home.php\";
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#c').modal('show');
            });
    </script>"
```

i also tried to change the

> $('#c').modal('show');

to

> $('#c').window('open');

but the modal still doesn't shows up, what should i do ?

Comment: You should put the `document.ready` function on the actual redirected page that you want to automatically open the modal. Generally, you could make use of a `GET` method to check for a specific redirect logic in case your page is used outside of your mentioned redirect logic.

Comment: thanks for the answer sir.
Yes putting '$('#c').window('open');' on my homepage does open the modal, but how do i do the get method part ? i tried [link] https://pastebin.com/6860CciV [/link] but it doesn't work.

Comment: `window.location = "\home.php?redirect=1"` and in your home.php `$redirect=$_GET['redirect'];` `if($redirect != "") { //open modal code here }`

Comment: no sir the modal still doesn't shows up that way.<br>
i tried to modify it to https://pastebin.com/2Cf29LPY, but that also not working

Comment: thanks sir i finally figured out how to do it based on your first answer

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your contribution guys, i solved the problem
this is how i done it :

1. set redirect page to `home.php#tryme`
2. give `id="tryme"` on the link for data input form
3. put this code to home.php:

> ```
>  <script>
>           $(document).ready(function() {
>                    var hash = window.location.hash;
>                    if (hash == "#tryme") {
>                         document.getElementById('tryme').click();
>                    }
>               });
>
>      </script>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, maybe you can add parameter in home.php, like `home.php?msg=success`.

 also move document.ready script to home.php and add if script inside your document.ready to check parameter msg.

```
if (msg != null OR msg != undefined), execute $('#c').modal('show');
```

cmiiw.